# How to remove summernote tooltip v.0.8.2

Tags: javascript, jquery, summernote

I'm trying to remove the tooltip from toolbar in summernote. I tried the following which worked previously but now doesn't work since update to 0.8.2. What would be the correct way to remove the tooltip?

```js
$("#myNote").summernote({
            toolbar: [
                ['para', ['ul']] // I want to remove this tooltip
            ],
            focus: true
        });
$('.note-editor [data-event="insertUnorderedList"]').tooltip('disable');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.2/summernote.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.2/summernote.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div id="myNote"></div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ugly way (I'll try to find something in the documentation to do something better) :

```js
$("#myNote").summernote({
            toolbar: [
                ['para', ['ul']] // I want to remove this tooltip
            ],
            focus: true
        });
$('.note-editor [data-event="insertUnorderedList"]').tooltip('disable');

$('.note-btn.btn.btn-default.btn-sm').attr('data-original-title','');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.2/summernote.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.2/summernote.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div id="myNote"></div>
```

Answer (score 6):

Use this

```
 $('#myTextEditorId').summernote({
                    tooltip: false
                });
```

note: Place summernote css files before bootstrap css

Answer (score 1):

Old post but i did like this:

```
$('.editor').summernote();
$('.note-btn').removeAttr('title');
```

Answer (score 0):

If without bootstrap, using lite sumernote.
Its look like summernote-lite.min.css and summernote-lite.min.js.

Ref:
[https://summernote.org/getting-started/][1]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).